# React - Redux App: "Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance" Issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

> At the beginning, that sample app was working properly. I could see
>   data that I inputted over browser page and database. At now, I can see
>   the data only via the database, the browser doesn't show data and getting this
>   error additionally: "Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable
>   instance".

There is the sample code :

**projectActions.js**

```
import {FETCH_BOOK, CREATE_BOOK, DELETE_BOOK} from '../actions/projectTypes';
import axios from 'axios';

const apiUrl = 'http://api/books';

export const createBookSuccess =  (data) => {
  return {
    type: CREATE_BOOK,
    payload: {
      _id: data._id,
      author: data.author,
      publication: data.publication,
      publisher: data.publisher
    }
  }
};

export const deleteBookSuccess = _id => {
  return {
    type: DELETE_BOOK,
    payload: {
      _id
    }
  }
};

export const fetchBook = (books) => {
  return {
    type: FETCH_BOOK,
    books
  }
};

export const createBook = ({ author, publication, publisher }) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    return axios.post(`${apiUrl}`, {author, publication, publisher})
      .then(response => {
        dispatch(createBookSuccess(response.data))
      })
      .catch(error => {
        throw(error);
      });
  };
};

export const deleteBook = _id => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    return axios.delete(`${apiUrl}/${_id}`)
      .then(response => {
        dispatch(deleteBookSuccess(response.data))
      })
      .catch(error => {
        throw(error);
      });
  };
};

export const fetchAllBooks = () => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    return axios.get(apiUrl)
      .then(response => {
        dispatch(fetchBook(response.data))
      })
      .catch(error => {
        throw(error);
      });
  };
};
```

**projectReducer.js**

```
import {CREATE_BOOK, DELETE_BOOK, FETCH_BOOK} from '../actions/projectTypes';

const projectReducer = (state = [], action) => {
  switch (action.types) {
    case CREATE_BOOK:
      return [...state, action.payload];
    case DELETE_BOOK:
      let afterDelete = state.filter(book => {
        return book._id !== action.payload._id
      });
      return {
        ...state,
        state: afterDelete
      }
    case FETCH_BOOK:
      return action.books;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default projectReducer;
```

**rootReducer.js**

```
import books from './projectReducer';
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    books: books
});

export default rootReducer;
```

**BookListElement.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import BookList from '../components/bookList';
import {deleteBook} from '../store/actions/projectActions';

const BookListElement= ({books, deleteBook}) => {
  if(!books.length) {
    return (
      <div>
        No Books
      </div>
    )
  }
  return (
    <div>
      {books.map(book => {
        return (
          <BookList book={book} deleteBook={deleteBook} key={book._id} />
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    books: state.books
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    deleteBook: _id => {
      dispatch(deleteBook(_id));
    }
  };
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(BookListElement);
```

**bookList.js**

```
import React from 'react';

const styles = {
  borderBottom: '2px solid #eee',
  background: '#fafafa',
  margin: '.75rem auto',
  padding: '.6rem 1rem',
  maxWidth: '500px',
  borderRadius: '7px'
};

const BookList =  ({ book: { author, publication, publisher, _id }, deleteBook }) => {
  return (
    <div style={styles} key={_id}>
      <h2>{author}</h2>
      <p>{publication}</p>
      <p>{publisher}</p>
      <button className="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="action" onClick={() => {deleteBook(_id)}}>
        <i className="large material-icons">delete_forever</i>
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default BookList;
```

**bookCreate.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class BookCreate extends Component {
  state= {
    author: '',
    publication: '',
    publisher: ''
  }

  handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.id]: e.target.value
    });
  }

  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.createBook(this.state)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} className="white" autoComplete="off">
          <h5 className="grey-text text-darken-3">Create New Book</h5>
          <div className="input-field">
            <label htmlFor="author">Author</label>
            <input type="text" id="author" onChange={this.handleChange}/>
          </div>

          <div className="input-field">
            <label htmlFor="publication">Publication</label>
            <input type="text" id="publication" onChange={this.handleChange}/>
          </div>

          <div className="input-field">
            <label htmlFor="publisher">Publisher</label>
            <input type="text" id="publisher" onChange={this.handleChange}/>
          </div>

          <div className="input-field">
            <button className="btn pink lighten-1 z-depth-0">Create</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default BookCreate;
```

> I checked the code a few times and read an older post about this issue
>   but I didn't find any solution as a junior. That would be great if you
>   say what did I miss.

EDIT: Added view.js file as bookList.js .

Comment: in what line do you have the error?

Comment: @DamianPeralta I run the code again and now ı don't get any error but still data doesn't display on browser. However, I can see via database.

Answer (score 21):

In your reducer, the state is supposed to be an array, but during deletion, you have returned an object:

```
case DELETE_BOOK:
  let afterDelete = state.filter(book => {
    return book._id !== action.payload._id
  });
  return afterDelete;
```

Comment: still doesn't work and displaying " No book " as a result.

Answer (score 20):

This error happens when you trying to copy an undefined array in your reducer. 
eg:

```
const newList = [...state.someList];
```

In this case 'someList' is undefined or not an array. make sure your spelling or you are using an correct array.

Comment: A simple workaround:

```const newList = state.someList ? [...state.someList] : [];```

Answer (score 15):

#### not necessary answering this question but maybe this helps someone who gets this error message and stumbles accross this SO-Post

I got this error as well. In my case the error was that **the element I tried to clone was in fact an object and not an array!**

This was what I ended up doing instead:

```
var clone = {...this.state.myObj};
```

(instead of)

```
var clone = [...this.state.myObj];
```

I know, really obvious but we all start somewhere, right?

Comment: or you have an undefined array !

Answer (score 0):

I think you should return your fetch response to reducer state and you can filter your deleted books in one line. maybe this would work.

```js
//projectReducer.js
import {CREATE_BOOK, DELETE_BOOK, FETCH_BOOK} from '../actions/projectTypes';

const projectReducer = (state = [], action) => {
  switch (action.types) {
    case CREATE_BOOK:
      return [...state, action.payload];
    case DELETE_BOOK:
      return state = state.filter(book => book._id !== action.payload._id)
    case FETCH_BOOK:
      return state = action.books;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default projectReducer;
```